# Merge tags [blockui] and [jquery-blockui]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

I'd like to propose merging the [blockui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blockui) and [jquery-blockui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-blockui) tags.

**Currently:**

**[blockui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blockui) x 194**

**[jquery-blockui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-blockui) x 133**

[blockui's about page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/blockui/info):

> jQuery plugin which prevents user activity with the page (or part of
>   the page) while it is triggered and until some action will unlock it.
>   BlockUI adds elements to the DOM to give it both the appearance and
>   behavior of blocking user interaction.

[jQuery-blockui's about page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-blockui/info):

> The jQuery BlockUI Plugin lets you simulate synchronous behavior when
>   using AJAX, without locking the browser. When activated, it will
>   prevent user activity with the page (or part of the page) until it is
>   deactivated. BlockUI adds elements to the DOM to give it both the
>   appearance and behavior of blocking user interaction.